# Partial backup restore of read-only file group on new database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, sql-server-2014

Let's say, I have a database `myModel2015` that contains two file groups - `Primary A` and `Secondary Read-Only B`. Then, I am creating a partial backup of the secondary file group.

Now, let's create a new `myModel` database (there might be difference in the database objects in the primary file group, but the tables in the read-only file group will be the same as this in the `myModel2015` database).

Is it possible to perform piecemeal restore of the `Secondary Read-Only B` file group but using the new database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this one covers it for you ([SE Link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9631/partial-restore-to-a-different-database))

He answers very succinctly, but as he says the short answer is no.   He also gives you some options that can work but none as simple as it would be if you could just restore that filegroup to a different database.

Answer (score 1):

While @mskiner's duplicate is correct, you cannot merge two databases via backup/restore methods within SQL, a more optimal solution to your given problem statement (a set of read-only objects), is to move all of those objects to their own database, making that database itself, read-only.

Utilize views or synonyms to references in one or more other databases to the objects in the "shared" read-only database on the same instance.